# Прерывается проверка списка в цикле

Tags: python, циклы, for

```
import os
import win32api

path = ['E:/keys.txt', 'G:/keys.txt']  # Эти файлы не существуют

result_path = path
for x in path:
    if os.path.isfile(x) is False:
        volume_lbl = win32api.GetVolumeInformation(x[:3])
        print(f'Ключ отсутствует на накопителе {x[:3]} с меткой {volume_lbl[0]}!')
        result_path.remove(x)
```

Функция должна проверять наличие файла по пути, содержащемся в списке. Проблема в том, что если файлы не существуют, цикл `for` прерывается, не доходя до конца списка `path`. После выполнения result_path будет содержать ['G:/keys.txt'], хотя по моей логике список должен остаться пустым.
Я пробовал инвертировать if, делать цикл while (а-ля C++) - не помогло.
Как починить?

Comment: курите deepcopy() , чем is отличается от == и.т.д.  У Вас result_path is path будет True. Это один и тот же объект.

Comment: На самом деле не очень понятно, зачем вам удалять элемент из списка

Comment: @Vasily чисто теоретически с точки зрения алгоритмов незачем, можно написать куда более производительный код. Но сам пример очень наглядно демонстрирует, как работает = в python с разными объектами...

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич это понятно, просто судя по контексту автор больше пишет на плюсах, по этому возможно лучше просто предложить готовое решение, так как не факт что автор будет в этом разбираться

Comment: @Vasily в конце функция должна вернуть result_path, поэтому оно там есть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё дело в модели управления памятью в python.

Вы создаёте объект **list**  *path*

Потом присваиваете *result_path* его "значение".

Внутри python это работает не так, как ожидает большинство новичков.

*result_path и path* ссылаются на один и тот же *list*.

В результате, при изменении в *result_path* изменяется *path*.
Это приводит к работе Вашего цикла for не как Вы задумывали.

Что делать?
Использовать например такие конструкции:

```
result_path  = deepcopy(path)
```

или

```
result_path  = list(path)
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы немного запутались в коде, нужно удалять элемент не из result_path, а из path. **НО** так вы будете удалять элемент из списка во время итерации по списку, что неправильно. И в целом не понятно, зачем вы удаляете элементы списка в вашем решении - я бы предложил просто удалить эту строку

```
import os
import win32api

path = ['E:/keys.txt', 'G:/keys.txt']  # Эти файлы не существуют

for x in path:
    if os.path.isfile(x) is False:
        volume_lbl = win32api.GetVolumeInformation(x[:3])
        print(f'Ключ отсутствует на накопителе {x[:3]} с меткой {volume_lbl[0]}!')
```